# Django install and enviroment are no longer recognized

Tags: python, django

I just went to run my Django development server in the Django project that I'm working on and I got this...

```
(baseballwebenv) C:\DjangoProjects\BaseballWebsite\baseballweb>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\envs\baseballwebenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Anaconda3\envs\baseballwebenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\version.py", line 4, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "c:\users\nick\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 178, in <module>
    from _winapi import (CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
ImportError: cannot import name 'ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

As you can see I am by my runserver command, I am in my virtual environment. I recently upgraded all of my Anaconda packages, thinking everything was protected in the virtual environment. I would suspect this problem is related to that, but I'm not sure. How do I get my project up and running again? If someone wants to see certain files, I can add those as well.

Comment: Do you have a requirements.txt file available for the project. Did you try installing all packages again from this ?

Comment: where would I find that file if I did have it avaiable?

Comment: please execute the command `pip freeze` for show packages and for requirement.txt `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: try `pip install django` again? and then `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to save list of packages?

Comment: pip freeze in my virtual environment, correct? Just want to make sure